# How can I use Trello with Internet Explorer 8?

Tags: trello, internet-explorer

Is it possible to run Trello on IE8?

I think it'd be a great way to share project information with clients, but I work with more than one client whose internal OS/browser standard is XP/IE8, with no plans to change in the immediate future.

Answer (score 5):

You (or your clients) can use Trello on IE8 after installing the [**Google Chrome Frame**](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/).

In fact, if you attempt to use Trello with IE8, you'll get a message that gives you that advice:

> **Your browser is not supported.**
>
> Trello supports [**Chrome 9**](http://www.google.com/chrome/) and above, [**Firefox 4**](http://www.firefox.com/) and above, [**Safari 5.0.5**](http://www.apple.com/safari/)
>   and above, and [**Internet Explorer 9**](http://www.microsoft.com/ie) and above.
>
> Internet Explorer 6, 7, and **8** support is available using Google Chrome
>   Frame. [**Download Google Chrome Frame**](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/).
>
> Please upgrade to use Trello. Thanks!

(from https://trello.com/not-supported.html)

**Note:** You should be able to install Chrome Frame [even if you don't have administrator privileges](http://blog.chromium.org/2011/08/non-admin-chrome-frame-reaches-stable.html) on the computer that you're using.

If you (or your clients) aren't able to install Chrome Frame, and aren't able to use another browser, then you (or they) won't be able to use Trello.  Sorry.

Comment: The problem is that some of the people I am trying to collaborate with are working in a large corporate environment where they have little or no ability to install a different browser, or even a new plugin for the browser they have.

Comment: @Tim: As I noted in my answer, you don't need admin privileges to install google chrome frame, so folks should be able to install it even in environments where they can't install new applications.

Comment: @Daniel: Sometimes group policies will prevent Google Frame from being installed even though admin priviledges are not required

Comment: If you are working under citrix, you have no chance to update or install any other browser and Cirtix experiencing problems with explorer 9, so it's not going to happen right now.